# php ajax form processing with spinner and error message

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I want to submit a form by php ajax and trying to keep things simple, but they are inevitably complicated.

`pageA.php` is just a form.

`pageB.php` is validating and processing code. On top of this page I created `$_SESSION['message'] = "";` and if something is wrong, at the end of page this could be `$_SESSION['message'] = "Password is too short";` - for example. 
This message I want to display on `pageA.php` - inside a div `#message`.

Sessions are started on top of both pages (`session_start();`
On `pageA` I also have a spinner gif, which is hidden by default (`display:none;`), but it should be visible during (and just during) form processing.

`pageA`.php

```
<form id="formReg" action="pageB.php" method="post">
. . .  
</form>
<img id="spinn" src="spinn.gif" />
<div id="message"></div>
<button id="sub">Register</button>
```

JS at the bottom of `pageA`:

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
    $("#spinn").show(); // it seems this works, but very shortly
    $.post( $("#formReg").attr("action"), $("#formReg").serialize()); // this works (data are stored in the table).
    $("#formReg :input").val(''); //this works
    $("#spinn").hide();
    $("#message").html($_Session["message"]); // doesn't work, of course.
});
```

At the bottom of `pageB.php` I have:
`header("Location: pageA.php");`, to keep visitors on `pageA`.

Comment: Are you actually using `Session["message"]` instead of `$_Session["message"]` in `$("#message").html(Session["message"]);`

Comment: @Sean, yes, thanks. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: All actions which should happen after the form submit must be placed in a callback function passed to `$.post()`. AJAX functions return immediately, therefore the spinner will be hidden shortly after it is shown. Do it like this:

```
$.post(
    $("#formReg").attr("action"), $("#formReg").serialize(), 
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $("#spinn").hide();
        // Message display code - see below
    }
);
```

That way, the code in the callback function gets executed as soon as the post request returns, not after the `$.post` call returns (which merely starts the request, but doesn't wait for it's completion).

Regarding displaying the message: Your `pageB.php` doesn't have to redirect, as it is only invoked via AJAX. So the client's browser will never leave `pageA.php` after opening it. The AJAX call is a separate HTTP request, which doesn't affect the page currently open. To return the value, you have to simply output it on `pageB` - the `data` parameter of the callback function defined above will contain it. If you want to keep it simple, just do:

```
// in pageB.php
echo $_SESSION['message'];

// In your JS callback
function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // "data" contains the output of pageB.php
    $("#message").html(data);
}
```

If you need to pass more than one item to your AJAX callback, take a look at [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Comment: lethal-guitar, thanks for both, the code and the explanation. I'll try. btw - cool nick.